# A closed form of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left[ H_n^2-\left(\ln n+\gamma+\frac1{2n} \right)^2\right]$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, closed-form, harmonic-numbers

The series of squares of [harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number)
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty H_n^2 \tag1
$$ is *divergent* since $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} H_n^2 \ne 0$, actually from the [classic result (6.3.18)](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_259.htm),
$$
H_n=\ln n+\gamma+\frac1{2n}+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right),\qquad  \, n \to \infty,
$$ where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant, one gets as $n \to \infty$, 
$$
H_n^2=\left(\ln n+\gamma+\frac1{2n} \right)^2+O\left(\frac{\ln n}{n^2}\right)\tag2
$$which tends to infinity.

Then the following *new* series

> $$
> \sum_{n=1}^\infty \color{grey}{\left[\color{#151515}{\: H_n^2-\left(\ln n+\gamma+\frac1{2n} \right)^2}\: \right]} \tag3
> $$

may be seen as a sort of regularization of $(1)$. The series $(3)$ is absolutely convergent as one may directly deduce from the comparison test with a Bertrand series, using $(2)$.

**Question**. *What is a closed form of $(3)$?*

My *intuition* is that $(3)$ admits a closed form in terms of [known constants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_constants_and_functions) (or [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_constant)).  I've used the advanced [Inverse Symbolic Calculator ISC $2.0$](https://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/advanced) but it found nothing. My recent attempt, not yet fruitful, has been to convert $(3)$ into an integral representation, starting  with
$$
\begin{align}
-\int_0^1\!\left(\!\frac1{\ln x}+\frac1{1-x}-\frac12\!\right)\!x^{n-1}\:dx&=H_n-\ln n-\gamma-\frac1{2n},\quad n\ge1,
\end{align}
$$ and trying to employ similar techniques used [here](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01558606/document).

Analogous considerations are [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/866382/a-closed-form-of-the-series-sum-n-1-infty-frach-n2-gamma-ln-n2) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1406122/conjectured-value-of-a-harmonic-sum-sum-n-1-infty-lefth-n-2h-2nh-4n), one may also explore some variations of $(3)$, like
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \color{grey}{\left[\color{#151515}{\: H_n^q-\left(\ln n+\gamma+\frac1{2n} \right)^q}\: \right]}, \,\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \!\color{grey}{\left[\color{#151515}{\: H_n^q-\left(\ln n+\gamma+\frac1{2n} \right)^q}\: \right]}.
$$

Comment: So the regularization of a series can simply be made by subtracting a few terms until the result converges? Seems to be a strange way to go about regularizing things.

Comment: A regularization of a divergent series is *not* unique...

Comment: Of course not. I just thought it strange to call that a regularization of the divergent series.

Comment: Please, feel free to suggest an appropriate word (english is not my native language).

Comment: I don't know if there is any correct term here. Personally, I'd call it a related series.

Comment: @ Olivier Oloa In another context (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2879699/evaluation-of-int-01-int-01-frac1-x-frac1x-y-dx-dy, and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2891159/asymptotic-behaviour-of-sums-involving-k-logk-and-h-k/2891453#2891453) I'm trying to calculate the asymptotic behaviour of the $\sum_{k=1}^n \log(k) H_{k}$. As this should appear also in a sum very similar to that in your OP here I wonder if the closed form of the sum $\sum_{k=1}^\infty (H_{k}-\log(k)-\gamma)^2 \simeq 0.323973$ has been calculated.

Comment: @Wolfgang Hintze I suggest you ask for a closed form of $$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty (H_{k}-\log(k)-\gamma)^2$$ in a separate question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The given series admits a closed form.

> **Proposition**.$$
> \sum_{n=1}^\infty \color{grey}{\left[\color{#151515}{\: H_n^2-\left(\ln n+\gamma+\frac1{2n} \right)^2}\: \right]}=\frac12\ln^2(2\pi)-\gamma\ln (2\pi)-\frac12\gamma^2-2\gamma_1-1. \qquad (\star)
> $$

where $\gamma_1$ is a [Stieltjes constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_constants).

(Sketch of a proof).

Let us consider, for $a\ge 0$,
$$
S(a):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \color{grey}{\left[\color{#151515}{\: \left(\psi(n+a+1)+\gamma\right)^2-\left(\ln (n+a)+\gamma+\frac1{2(n+a)} \right)^2}\: \right]}, \tag1
$$
where throughout  $\displaystyle \psi :=\left(\text{Log}\: \Gamma  \right)'$ is the digamma function. From the standard identity
$$
\psi(n+1)+\gamma=H_n\qquad n=1,2,\cdots,\tag2
$$
we have
$$
S(0)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \color{grey}{\left[\color{#151515}{\: H_n^2-\left(\ln n+\gamma+\frac1{2n} \right)^2}\: \right]}. \tag3
$$
One is allowed to differentiate $S(a)$ termwise obtaining
$$
\begin{align}
S'(a)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty &\left[2\:\psi'(n+a+1)\left(\psi(n+a+1)+\gamma\right)\color{#FFFFFF}{\frac2{(n+a)}}\right.
\\&-\left.\left(\frac2{(n+a)}-\frac1{(n+a)^2}\right)\!\left(\ln (n+a)+\gamma+\frac1{2(n+a)} \right)\right], \tag4
\end{align}
$$ then we are lead to consider the partial sum,
$$
\begin{align}
S_N'(a)=&\sum_{n=1}^N 2\:\psi'(n+a+1)\left(\psi(n+a+1)+\gamma\right)
\\-&\sum_{n=1}^N\left(\frac2{(n+a)}-\frac1{(n+a)^2}\right)\left(\ln (n+a)+\gamma+\frac1{2(n+a)} \right).\tag5
\end{align}
$$ We have proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2085313/asymptotic-behavior-of-harmonic-like-series-sum-n-1k-psin-psin/2089162#2089162) that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^N \psi'(n)\psi(n)$ has a closed form, this result can be extended as follows.

> **Theorem**. Let $a$ be any non-negative real number. We have
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> &\sum_{n=1}^N \psi'(n+a+1)\psi(n+a+1)
> \\&=\left((N+a+1) \psi(N+a+2)-(a+1)\psi(a+2)\right)' \psi(N+a+1)
> \\\\&-\left((N+a+1) \psi(N+a+2)-(a+2)\psi(a+3)\right)' 
> \\\\&+\left((a+1)\psi(a+2)\right)'\left(\psi(N+a+1)-\psi(a+2)\right)
>  \tag6
> \\\\&+\frac12 \psi'(N+a+1)-\frac12\psi'(a+2)-\frac12 \left(\psi'(N+a+1)\right)^2+\frac12 \left(\psi'(a+2)\right)^2.
> \end{align}
> $$

*Proof*. One uses a [summation by parts](https://en.wikipaedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts#Statement) with
$$
f_n(a)=\psi(n+a+1),\quad g_n(a)=\psi'(n+a+1),\quad n\ge1,
$$ taking into account that
$$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{n=1}^N \psi'(n+a+1)=\left((N+a+1) \psi(N+a+2)-(a+1)\psi(a+2)\right)'. \tag7
\end{align}
$$ 
Then the second sum on the right hand side of $(5)$ satisfies
$$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{n=1}^N\left(\frac2{(n+a)}-\frac1{(n+a)^2}\right)\left(\ln (n+a)+\gamma+\frac1{2(n+a)}\right)
\\\\&=2\gamma_1(a+1)-2\gamma_1(N+a+1)+2\gamma \psi(N+a+1)-2\gamma\psi(a+1)
 \tag8
\\\\&+\frac14 \psi''(N+a+1)-\frac14\psi''(a+2)+\gamma_1'(a+1)-\gamma_1'(N+a+1)
\\\\&+(\gamma+1)\psi'(N+a+1)-(\gamma+1)\psi'(a+1),
\end{align}
$$
where we have used the [generalized Stieltjes constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_constants#Generalized_Stieltjes_constants),
$$
\begin{align}
\gamma_1(a+1)=\lim_{N \to \infty}\left(\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{\ln(n+a)}{n+a}-\frac12\:\ln^2 \left(N+a\right)\right).
\end{align}
$$ 
We then insert $(6)$, $(7)$ and $(8)$ into $(5)$ and let $N \to \infty$ to get

$$
\begin{align}
S'(a)=&\:\left(2a-2(a+2)\psi(a+3)\right)'+\left(2\gamma a-2\gamma(a+1)\psi(a+2)\right)'
\\\\-&\:\left(\psi(a+2)-(a+1) \left(\psi(a+2)\right)^2\right)'-2\gamma_1(a+1)+2\gamma\psi(a+1)
 \tag9
\\\\+&\frac14\psi''(a+2)-\gamma_1'(a+1)+(\gamma+1)\psi'(a+1).
\end{align}
$$
Finally, integrating $(9)$ using
$$
2\int_1^{1+a}\gamma_1(t)\:dt=\zeta''(0,a+1)-\zeta''(0),
$$ where $\zeta(\cdot,\cdot)$ denotes the [Hurwitz zeta](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HurwitzZetaFunction.html) function and where $\zeta''(0,a+1)=\left.\partial_s^2\zeta(s,a+1)\right|_{s=0}$, determining the  constant of integration by letting $a \to \infty$ and using $(3)$ yields $(\star)$.

Comment: Nice. Using Pari GP and having enough digits one could have guessed the exact value.

Comment: @Olivier Oloa: great ! (+1) I still need to fully understand the proof, but it looks like a recipe to solve many similar problems.

Comment: @Olivier Oloa : would your method also work for the next (2nd) order of approximating the harmonic numbers, i.e. has $s2$ a closed form where $s2=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \left(H_n^2-\left(-\frac{1}{12 n^2}+\frac{1}{2 n}+\left(\gamma +\log n \right)\right)^2\right)$ ? In this case the sum is positive: $s2 = 0.01424761677 ...$.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze Thanks. It's the first time I use this method to obtain the closed form of such a series, yes I think the method is applicable to a large class. Concerning your series $s2$ I'm afraid the closed form needs some work to be dug up.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze I find that $$s2=s1+\frac{ \pi ^2}{3} \log A+\frac{1}{12}\zeta (3)-\frac{\pi ^4}{12960}-\frac{\pi ^2 }{36} \log (2 \pi )$$ where $s1$ is the *original sum*.

Comment: @Olivier Oloa Congratulations ! Just a question: what is A? Based on your results I find A = 1.282427 ...

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze $A=1.2824271291006226368753425688697917\cdots$ is the Glaisher-Kinkelin constant, it arises when one considers the asymptotic behaviour of $1^1\cdot 2^2 \cdot 3^3 \cdots n^n$ as $n \to \infty$. One has $$\ln A= \frac{1}{12}-\zeta'(-1)$$ where $\zeta(\cdot)$ is the Riemann zeta function. See the original paper of J.L. Glaisher (1878): http://www.archive.org/stream/messengermathem01glaigoog#page/n57/mode/1up

Comment: @Olivier Oloa Thank you. By the way, I just stumbled on this constant trying (unsuccessful up to now) to find the asymptotics of $\sum _{k=1}^n \log ^2(k)$ which appears in the attempt to evaluate directly the partial sum of s1 similar to Jack D'Aurizio.

Comment: @Olivier Oloa Another question regarding your derivation for s1: How did you calcultate the limit $a \to \infty$ of the second derivative of the Hurwitz zeta function $\zeta''(0,a+1)=\left.\partial_s^2\zeta(s,a+1)\right|_{s=0}$ and what is the result ?

Comment: One may differentiate twice a representation of the Hurwitz zeta function by the Euler–Maclaurin Formula: http://dlmf.nist.gov/25.11#E7 then one may work with it as $a \to \infty$. The result is corollary 2 p. 169 here (start from section 3): https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pja/1195506664

Answer (score 11):

Just some considerations for now.

I have proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/933714/44121) that
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{N}H_n^2 = (N+1) H_N^2-(2N+1)H_N+2N \tag{$\color{blue}{1}$} $$
and we have:
$$ \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{\log x+\gamma}{x}\right)(s)=-\log(s)\tag{2} $$
$$ \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{\left(\log x+\gamma\right)^2}{x}\right)(s)=-\zeta(2)+\log^2(s)\tag{3} $$
hence the partial sums of the given series can be rearranged as follows:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left[H_n^2-\left(\log n+\gamma+\frac{1}{2n}\right)^2\right]&=&(\color{blue}{1})-\frac{H_N^{(2)}}{4}-\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{\log n+\gamma}{n}-\sum_{n=1}^{N}n\frac{(\log n+\gamma)^2}{n}\\&=&(\color{blue}{1})-\frac{H_N^{(2)}}{4}+\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\log(s)(1-e^{-Ns})}{e^s-1}\,ds\\&-&\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-N s} \left(e^{(1+N) s}+N-e^s (1+N)\right)\left(\zeta(2)-\log^2 s\right)}{\left(-1+e^s\right)^2}\,ds\end{eqnarray*}$$

If we find a way to distribute $(\color{blue}{1})$ over the last two integrals, in a way ensuring they are convergent integrals as $N\to +\infty$, we are done. At first sight the closed form of the LHS appears to be related with $\zeta(2)$, $\zeta'(0)=-\frac{1}{2}\log(2\pi)$ and
$$ \zeta''(0)=\frac{\gamma^2}{2}-\frac{\pi ^2}{24}-\frac{1}{2}\log^2(2\pi)+\gamma_1$$
with $\gamma_1$ being a [Stieltjes constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_constants). An alternative, brute-force way is just to compute the asymptotic expansions of
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{N}\log^2(n),\qquad \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{\log(n)}{n} $$
with the sufficient degree of accuracy (I guess that to stop at the $O\left(\frac{1}{N^3}\right)$ term is enough), that is just a tedious exercise about summation by parts.

Comment: You can replace $\sum_{n=1}^N (\log n)^2$ by $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\log n)^2 n^{-s}$ or even
$\int_0^\infty x^{s-1}(\log x)^2 \frac{1}{e^x-1} dx$.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio  "that is just a tedious exercise about summation by parts. " Could you please explain this in more detail? Particular example: how does one calculate the asymptotic behaviour of $\sum _{n=1}^N \log ^2(n)$ for $N\to \infty$

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze: I meant that the asymptotic behaviour of $\sum_{n=2}^{k}\log(k)=\log(k!)=\log\Gamma(k+1)$ is well-known, as well as the asymptotic behaviour of $\log(n+1)-\log(n)=\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2n^2}+\ldots$, hence the problem boils down to plugging in such asymptotics into $$ \sum_{n=2}^{N}\log(n!)\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right).$$

Comment: The same applies to the second sum, which by summation by parts boils down to $$ \sum_{n=1}^{N} H_n \log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right).$$

Answer (score 3):

An integral representation for the series

Let,

$\begin{align}
u_n:=H_n-\ln n-\gamma-\dfrac{1}{2n}\\
v_n:=H_n+\ln n+\gamma+\dfrac{1}{2n}\\
\end{align}$

Observe that,

$\begin{align}u_n+v_n\end{align}=2H_n$

Since,

$\displaystyle H_n=-n\int_0^1 x^{n-1}\ln(1-x)\ dx$

and,

$\displaystyle u_n=-\int_0^1 \left(\frac{1}{\ln x}+\frac{1}{1-x}-\frac{1}{2}\right)x^{n-1}\ dx$

then,

$\begin{align}v_n&=2H_n-u_n\\
&=-2n\int_0^1 x^{n-1}\ln(1-x)\ dx+\int_0^1 \left(\frac{1}{\ln x}+\frac{1}{1-x}-\frac{1}{2}\right)x^{n-1}\ dx
\end{align}$

therefore,

$\begin{align}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}u_nv_n&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(2n\int_0^1 \int_0^1\ln(1-x)\left(\frac{1}{\ln y}+\frac{1}{1-y}-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)(xy)^{n-1}\ dx\ dy-\\
&\int_0^1\int_0^1 \left(\frac{1}{\ln x}+\frac{1}{1-x}-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{1}{\ln y}+\frac{1}{1-y}-\frac{1}{2}\right)(xy)^{n-1}\ dx\ dy\\
&=2\int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x)}{(1-xy)^2}\left(\frac{1}{\ln y}+\frac{1}{1-y}-\frac{1}{2}\right)\ dx\ dy-\\
&\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{1}{1-xy} \left(\frac{1}{\ln x}+\frac{1}{1-x}-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{1}{\ln y}+\frac{1}{1-y}-\frac{1}{2}\right)\ dx\ dy\\
&=\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \left(\frac{2\ln(1-x)}{(1-xy)^2}-\frac{1}{1-xy}\left(\frac{1}{\ln x}+\frac{1}{1-x}-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)\left(\frac{1}{\ln y}+\frac{1}{1-y}-\frac{1}{2}\right)\ dx\ dy\\
&=\boxed{2A-B}
\end{align}$

and,

$\begin{align}A&=\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x)}{(1-xy)^2}\left(\frac{1}{\ln y}+\frac{1}{1-y}-\frac{1}{2}\right)\ dx\ dy\\
B&=\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{1}{1-xy}\left(\frac{1}{\ln x}+\frac{1}{1-x}-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{1}{\ln y}+\frac{1}{1-y}-\frac{1}{2}\right)\ dx\ dy
\end{align}$

( [Computation of A](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20ln(1-x)%2F(1-x*y)%5E2*(1%2Fln(y)%2B1%2F(1-y)-1%2F2)%20x%3D0,1,y%3D0,1) )

( [Computation of B](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%201%2F(1-x*y)*(1%2Fln(x)%2B1%2F(1-x)-1%2F2)*(1%2Fln(y)%2B1%2F(1-y)-1%2F2)%20x%3D0,1,y%3D0,1) )

**Addenda**:

1)
$\begin{align}A=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-y)}{y(1-y)}\left(\frac{1}{\ln y}+\frac{1}{1-y}-\frac{1}{2}\right)\ dy
\end{align}$

(one can simplify this integral)

$A\approx -0.1932$

( [Computation of A](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20log(1-y)%2F(y*(1-y))*(1%2Flog(y)%2B1%2F(1-y)-1%2F2),y%3D0,1) )

$\begin{align}B&=\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{1}{1-xy}\left(\frac{1}{\ln x}+\frac{1}{1-x}\right)\left(\frac{1}{\ln y}+\frac{1}{1-y}-1\right)\ dx\ dy+\frac{\pi^2}{24}
\end{align}$

2)
Since,

$\displaystyle \gamma=\int_0^1 \left(\frac{1}{\ln x}+\frac{1}{1-x}\right)\ dx$

then

$\begin{align}B&=\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{xy}{1-xy}\left(\frac{1}{\ln x}+\frac{1}{1-x}\right)\left(\frac{1}{\ln y}+\frac{1}{1-y}-1\right)\ dx\ dy+\gamma^2-\gamma+\frac{\pi^2}{24}\end{align}$

$B\approx 0.00651229$

([Computation of B](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20x*y%2F(1-x*y)*(1%2Flog(x)%2B1%2F(1-x))*(1%2Flog(y)%2B1%2F(1-y)-1)%2Beulergamma%5E2-eulergamma%2BPi%5E2%2F24,x%3D0,1,y%3D0,1) )

3)
$\begin{align}A&=\int_0^1\left[\left(\frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}+\frac{\ln(1-x)}{1-x}\right)\left(\frac{1}{\ln x}+\frac{1}{1-x}\right)-\frac{1}{2}\times \frac{\ln(1-x)}{1-x}\right]\ dx+\frac{\pi^2}{12}\end{align}$

( [Computation of A](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20(log(1-x)%2Fx%2Blog(1-x)%2F(1-x))*(1%2Flog(x)%2B1%2F(1-x))-1%2F2*log(1-x)%2F(1-x)%2BPi%5E2%2F12,x%3D0,1) )

Comment: a value with 30 or 40 digits would be nice to try to guess a closed form (LLL stuff)

Comment: Have you performed some LLL stuff  (lindep in GP PARI) using constants $\zeta(2),\gamma_1,\log(2\pi)$...?

Comment: I've just used ISC 2.0.

Comment: Sometimes, if you're lucky enough, lindep is better that ISC 2.0 Please provide a bunch of digits.

Comment: @FDP I'm surprised that your integrand seems not to be symmetric in x and y.

Comment: Why should they be symmetric? Maybe my computations contain errors. The series converges slowly it's difficult to get a bunch of digits.

Comment: @FDP I would greatly appreciate if you could identify your final expression which is meant to represent the sum.

Comment: Sorry, I dont have a clue how to compute these two integrals for now. The first one can be simplified a little bit. I would like to compute something like hundred digits to try to guess the value of this sum. I hope the sum can be expressed as $a\zeta(2)+b\gamma_1+c\ln(2\pi)$ (a,b,c rationals) or something like that.

Comment: @FDP Your solution cannot be correct as it gives a wrong numerical result. The value of the sum of the OP with 10^4 terms  is approximately -0.392733 whereas your result is A (the y-integral) - B with A = -0.1932 and B = 0.00651229 giving -0.199712.

Comment: Dr Wolfgang Hintze: Your values are correct but sum=2A-B (i have updated my "solution")

Comment: @FDP For your updated version I find numerically A = -0.0990267, B = 0.00602467 so that 2A - B = -0.204078 which is wrong again. You have now returned to double integrals leading to a wrong numerical value for the sum. I had from the beginning a double integral which gave the correct numerical result, nd have provided additional material. Hence I found the distribution of reputation points not fair: (-1)

Comment: Dr. Wolfgang Hintzel: your value for A is incorrect: www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+log(1-x)%2F(1-xy)%5E2*(1%2Flog(y)%2B1%2F(1-y)-1%2F2),x%3D0,1,y%3D0,1

Comment: I have updated my "solution" with the links to compute  A,B with WA

Comment: @FDP you are right, your last definition of A (single integral) gives -0.1932. Unfortunately, your definitions changed somewhat randomly so I got confused.

Answer (score 2):

We derive a representation of the sum in question $f$ as a double integral with a symmetric integrand. Transformation to polar coordinates leads to a explicitly "innocent" expression for the integrand in the domain of interest.
It is proposed to develop the integrand into a power series. The developments are under way.

Letting

$$d(n)=\frac{1}{2 n}+\log (n)+\gamma$$

the nth summand becomes

$$s(n)=H(n)^2-d(n)^2$$

and the sum is

$$f=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } s(n)$$

We now use the integral representations

$$d(n)\to  \int_0^1 \left(x^{n-1} \left(\frac{1}{1-x}+\frac{1}{\log (x)}-\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}\right) \, dx$$

and

$$H(n)\to \int_0^1 \frac{1-x^n}{1-x} \, dx$$

and replace the terms in the summand which then becomes a double integral (sorry for the bad Latex)

$$si(n)=\int _0^1\int _0^1\left(\frac{\left(1-x^n\right) \left(1-y^n\right)}{(1-x) (1-y)}-\left(x^{n-1} \left(\frac{1}{1-x}+\frac{1}{\log (x)}-\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}\right) \left(y^{n-1} \left(\frac{1}{1-y}+\frac{1}{\log (y)}-\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{1-y^n}{1-y}\right)\right)dydx$$

The sum of $si(n)$ over $n$ can be easily done.

$$si=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } si(n)$$

The result, called $sa1$ and is the integrand for the positive quantity $-f$ in what follows, is

$$\text{sa1}=\frac{\left(\frac{1}{1-x}+\frac{1}{\log (x)}-\frac{1}{2}\right) \left(\frac{1}{1-y}+\frac{1}{\log (y)}-\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{\frac{1}{1-x}+\frac{1}{\log (x)}-\frac{1}{2}}{1-x}+\frac{\frac{1}{1-y}+\frac{1}{\log (y)}-\frac{1}{2}}{1-y}}{1-x y}$$

Now we make two subsequent coordinate transformations

1. x-> Exp[-u], y->Exp[-v]
2. u->r Cos[a], v-> r Sin[a], 0<=r, 0<=a<=pi/2

This defines sa3. Instead of giving the lengthy expression we show the plot

[image]

The plot shows that sa3 is a pretty innocent function.

$-f$ is now given by the integral of $sa3$ over $r$ from $0$ to $\infty$ and over $a$ from $0$ to $\pi/2$.

A numerical check gives sufficient agreement between direct sum with 10^4 terms (|sum| = 0.392733) and this integral (int =0.392733 ) to see that the integrand is correct.

*Expansion of the integrand in a series of powers of $(a-\pi/4)$*

I was not able to do the integral in symbolic form (neither of the two).  The plot shows, however, that the dependence of the integrand on $a$ is weak so that it seems reasonable to expand the integrand in a series of (even) powers of $(a-\pi/4)$ the coefficients of which are integrals over $r$ which seem not impossible to be done in closed form.

The first term of this development (equal to $sa3$ for $a = \pi/4$) is

$$sa3(a=\pi/4)= \frac{\left(\sqrt{2} e^{\frac{r}{\sqrt{2}}} r+\sqrt{2} r-4 e^{\frac{r}{\sqrt{2}}}+4\right) \left(5 \sqrt{2} e^{\frac{r}{\sqrt{2}}} r+\sqrt{2} r-4 e^{\frac{r}{\sqrt{2}}}+4\right)}{8 \left(e^{\frac{r}{\sqrt{2}}}-1\right)^2 \left(e^{\sqrt{2} r}-1\right) r}$$

Mathematica refused to solve that integral.

*Behaviour of the integrand close to the origin*

The behaviour of the integrand close to the origin is not easily found in the x-y-representation, but it is easy in polar coordinates: $sa3$ close to the origin is found by expanding it into a series of powers of $r$ and doing the a-integral exactly. The first four terms are

$$ \frac{\tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}{3 \sqrt{2}}  -r \frac{\pi }{48}  -r^2 \left(\frac{1}{144}-\frac{\tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}{240 \sqrt{2}}\right)+\frac{r^3}{480}+r^4 \left(\frac{149}{181440}-\frac{\tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}{12096 \sqrt{2}}\right)$$

Numerically,

$$0.207742 -0.0654498 r-0.00434767 r^2+0.00208333 r^3+0.000769685 r^4$$

To be continued.

Comment: Thank you @Dr Wolfgang Hintze. (+1)