# Prove $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \binom{s}{n} \frac{H_{n+1/2}+\log 4}{n+1} =\frac{2^{2s+1}}{(2s+1) (s+1) {2s \choose s}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, generating-functions, closed-form, harmonic-numbers

> Is there an elegant proof for this identity for all real $s \neq -1, -1/2$?
>
> $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \binom{s}{n}  \frac{H_{n+1/2}+\log 4}{n+1} =\frac{2^{2s+1}}{(2s+1) (s+1) {2s \choose s}}$$

Where $H_x$ represents harmonic numbers.

I found it in a very roundabout way for $s=0,1,2,3,\dots$, (see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3309542/269624) and [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3294617/269624)) and I don't actually have the proof for the other identity I used:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{H_{k-\frac{1}{2}}}{k} x^n= \frac{2}{x(1-x)} \left( \operatorname{arctanh}^2 \sqrt{x}+\log 2 \log (1-x) \right)$$

So whichever one you can prove works fine for me, but I think the first series should be easier to prove.

Using Ali Shather's comment, we can simplify:

> $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \binom{s}{n}  \frac{2H_{2n}-H_n}{n+1} =\frac{2^{2s+1}}{(2s+1) (s+1) {2s \choose s}}$$

One of the interesting consequences:

$$\frac{1}{x} \arcsin^2 \sqrt{x}=\sum_{l=0}^\infty \frac{(4 x)^l}{(2l+1) (l+1) {2l \choose l}}$$

Comment: Nice .. by the way we can write $H_{k-\frac12}=2H_{2k}-H_k-2\ln2$

Comment: Please also define $H$ here, so that the question is self-contained.

Comment: @AliShather, thank you, this looks much neater, I'll edit once I'm on laptop

Comment: @Yuriy S no problem. I am preparing  a partial solution. I hope you will find it helpful.

Comment: My comment comes after going to the first link and searching for the $H$, then to the second link and searching for the $H$, then looking again at the identity, just something like "harmonic number (with a real argument)" in the text would be helpful. I also said "*please* define..."

Comment: @Yuriy S here is a proof for the identity i provided in case it matters https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10219402638875565&set=p.10219402638875565&type=3&theater

Answer (score 2):

**Partial solution to the second double sum**:

Lets work on the inner sum first
\begin{align}
S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{H_{k-\frac12}}{k}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{H_{k-\frac12}}{k}+\frac{H_{n+\frac12}}{n+1}
\end{align}

by substituting  $\ H_{k-\frac12}=2H_{2k}-H_k-2\ln2$, to have

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{H_{k-\frac12}}{k}&=2\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{H_{2k}}{k}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{H_k}{k}-2\ln2\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}\\
&=2\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{H_{2k}}{k}-\left(\frac{H_n^2+H_n^{(2)}}{2}\right)-2\ln2H_n\\
\end{align}

Therefore
$$S_n=2\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{H_{2k}}{k}-\left(\frac{H_n^2+H_n^{(2)}}{2}\right)-2\ln2H_n+\frac{H_{n+\frac12}}{n+1}\tag{1}$$

Which follows that

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{H_{k-\frac12}}{k}\right)x^n=2\underbrace{\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{H_{2k}}{k}x^n}_{\Large S_1}-\underbrace{\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(H_n^2+H_n^{(2)}\right)x^n}_{\Large S_2}-2\ln2\underbrace{\sum_{n=0}^\infty H_nx^n}_{\Large S_3}+\underbrace{\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{H_{n+\frac12}}{n+1}x^n}_{\Large S_4}$$.

---

Starting with $S_2$ and by using the following identity: ( proved by SuperAbound [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/908585))

$$\frac{\ln^2(1-x)}{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(H_n^2-H_n^{(2)}\right)x^n\tag{2}$$

Add $\ \displaystyle2\sum_{n=0}^\infty H_n^{(2)}x^n=\frac{2\operatorname{Li}_2(x)}{1-x}$ to both sides of $(2)$, we get
$$\boxed{S_2=\frac{2\operatorname{Li}_2(x)+\ln^2(1-x)}{1-x}}$$

---

$$\boxed{S_3=-\frac{\ln(1-x)}{1-x}}$$

---

and the last sum
\begin{align}
S_4&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{H_{n+\frac12}}{n+1}x^n\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{n-\frac12}}{n}x^{n-1}\\
&=\frac1x\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{2H_{2n}-H_n-2\ln2}{n}\right)x^n\\
&=\frac2x\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_{2n}}{n}x^n-\frac1x\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_{n}}{n}x^n-\frac{2\ln2}x\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n}\\
&=\frac2x\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_{2n}}{n}x^n-\frac1x(\operatorname{Li}_2(x)+\frac12\ln^2(1-x))-\frac{2\ln2}x(-\ln(1-x))\\
\end{align}

The remaining sum can be simplified as follows:

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_{2n}}{n}x^n&=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_{2n}}{2n}(\sqrt{x})^{2n}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_{n}}{n}(\sqrt{x})^n(1+(-1)^n)\\
&=\operatorname{Li}_2(\sqrt{x})+\frac12\ln^2(1-\sqrt{x})+\operatorname{Li}_2(-\sqrt{x})+\frac12\ln^2(1+\sqrt{x})\\
&=\frac12\operatorname{Li}_2(x)+\frac12\ln^2(1-\sqrt{x})+\frac12\ln^2(1+\sqrt{x})
\end{align}

Thus 
$$\boxed{S_4=\frac1x\left(\ln^2(1-\sqrt{x})+\ln^2(1+\sqrt{x})-\frac12\ln^2(1-x)+2\ln2\ln(1-x)\right)}$$

---

I hope someone will take care of $S_1$ and I hope you find my attempt helpful.

Comment: @ Ali Shather As far as I can see I have already calculated $S_1$ in a comment to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2910223/closed-form-of-finite-euler-sum-sum-k-1n-frac-h-k2k1/3309746#3309746 Yurij S and you have even proposed simplified versions of my result.

Comment: @Dr. Wolfgang Hintze thank you for reminding me. that was such a blunder. let me put all the results together and see what i get.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a path for getting

> $$
> \sum_{\substack{0\le n\\1\le k\le(n+1)}}
> \frac 1k\cdot H_{k-1/2}\; x^n
> = 
> \frac{2}{x(1-x)} 
> \Big( \operatorname{arctanh}^2 \sqrt{x}
> +
> \log 2 \log (1-x) \Big)\ .
> $$
>   (We show this holds as an equality of meromorphic functions in the open 
>   unit disk in the complex plane.)

Using $$H_{k-1/2}=(2H_{2k}-H_k)-2\log 2\ ,$$the relation to be shown splits in two parts, we consider them separately. The simpler part is the one with coefficients (in each $x^n$) in $2\log 2\cdot\Bbb Q$, we consider it first, it is a good warm-up. The slightly more complicated part with rationaly coefficients (in $x^n$) is similar, we need to write the Cauchy product of two series, one being again $1/(1-x)=(1+x+x^2+x^3+\dots)$, with more care.

---

The simpler series, we substitute $N=n+1\ge1$ explicitly, to make it simpler for the bare eye to follow at one glance:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{\substack{0\le n\\1\le k\le(n+1)}}
\frac 1k\; x^n
&=
\frac 1x
\sum_{\substack{1\le N\\1\le k\le N}}
\frac 1k\; x^N
\\
&=\frac 1x\sum_{1\le N}\left(\frac 11+\frac 12+\dots+\frac 1N\right)x^N
\\
&=\frac 1x
(1+x+\dots+x^N+\dots)
\left(\frac x1+\frac {x^2}2+\dots+\frac {x^N}N+\dots\right)
\\
&=\frac 1x
\cdot\frac 1{1-x}
\cdot\Big(\ -\ln(1-x)\ \Big)\ .
\end{aligned}
$$

---

The other part is similar. We isolate the same type of a Cauchy product, one of the factors being $1/(1-x)$. After multiplication with $x$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
x\sum_{\substack{0\le n\\1\le k\le(n+1)}}
\frac 1k(2H_{2k}-H_k)\; x^n
&=
\sum_{\substack{1\le N\\1\le k\le N}}
\frac 1k(2H_{2k}-H_k)\; x^N
\\
&\qquad\text{ and we keep this in mind, on the other side,}
\\
&\qquad\text{ using $y=\sqrt x$:}
\\[3mm]
x\cdot\frac{2}{x(1-x)} 
\operatorname{arctanh}^2 \sqrt{x}
&=
\frac 2{1-y^2}\left(\sum_{j\ge 1\text{ odd}}\frac 1j y^j\right)^2
\\
&=
\frac 2{1-y^2}\sum_{2\le M\text{ even}}
\sum_{\substack{
j\ge 1\text{ odd}\\
k\ge 1\text{ odd}\\
j+k = M
}}\frac 1j\cdot \frac 1k \; y^M
\\
&=
2\Big(1+y^2+y^4+y^6+\dots\Big)\sum_{2\le M\text{ even}}
\sum_{\substack{
j\ge 1\text{ odd}\\
k\ge 1\text{ odd}\\
j+k = M
}}\frac 1j\cdot \frac 1k \; y^M
\\
&=
2
\sum_{2\le M\text{ even}}
\sum_{\substack{
j\ge 1\text{ odd}\\
k\ge 1\text{ odd}\\
j+k \le M
}}
\frac 1j\cdot \frac 1k \; y^M
\text{ and with $M=2N$, $x=y^2$,}
\\
&=
2
\sum_{1\le N\text{ arbitrary}}
\sum_{\substack{
j\ge 1\text{ odd}\\
k\ge 1\text{ odd}\\
j+k \le 2N
}}
\frac 1j\cdot \frac 1k \; x^N
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
Let us try now to figure out the simplification scheme for the two expressions of the coefficients in $x^N$, $N$ integer $\ge 1$, for a fixed small value of $N$. We take $N=5$. The sum over the $\frac 1j\cdot \frac 1k$ with odd $j,k\ge 1$, having sum $\le 2N$ has the terms explicitly:
$$
\text{twice}\qquad
\begin{array}{ccccc}
\frac 11\cdot \frac 11 &
\frac 11\cdot \frac 13 &
\frac 11\cdot \frac 15 &
\frac 11\cdot \frac 17 &
\color{magenta}{\frac 11\cdot \frac 19 }
\\
\frac 13\cdot \frac 11 &
\frac 13\cdot \frac 13 &
\frac 13\cdot \frac 15 &
\color{magenta}{\frac 13\cdot \frac 17} &
\\
\frac 15\cdot \frac 11 &
\frac 15\cdot \frac 13 &
\color{magenta}{\frac 15\cdot \frac 15} &
&
\\
\frac 17\cdot \frac 11 &
\color{magenta}{\frac 17\cdot \frac 13} &
&
&
\\
\color{magenta}{\frac 19\cdot \frac 11} &
&
&
&
\end{array}
$$
The other side is
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{1\le k\le N}
\frac 1k(2H_{2k}-H_k)
=&
\frac 11\left(\frac 21\color{blue}{+\frac 22-\frac 11}\right)
\\
+&
\frac 12\left(\frac 21\color{blue}{+\frac 22}+\frac 23\color{blue}{+\frac 24-\frac 11-\frac 12}\right)
\\
+&
\frac 13\left(\frac 21\color{blue}{+\frac 22}+\frac 23\color{blue}{+\frac 24}+\frac 25\color{blue}{+\frac 26-\frac 11-\frac 12-\frac 13}\right)
\\
+&
\frac 14\left(\frac 21\color{blue}{+\frac 22}+\frac 23\color{blue}{+\frac 24}+\frac 25\color{blue}{+\frac 26}+\frac 27\color{blue}{+\frac 28-\frac 11-\frac 12-\frac 13-\frac 14}\right)
\\
+&
\frac 14\left(\frac 21\color{blue}{+\frac 22}+\frac 23\color{blue}{+\frac 24}+\frac 25\color{blue}{+\frac 26}+\frac 27\color{blue}{+\frac 28}+\frac 29\color{blue}{+\frac 2{10}-\frac 11-\frac 12-\frac 13-\frac 14-\frac 15}\right)
\\[3mm]
=&
\frac 11\left(\frac 21\right)
\\
+&
\frac 12\left(\frac 21+\frac 23\right)
\\
+&
\frac 13\left(\frac 21+\frac 23+\frac 25\right)
\\
+&
\frac 14\left(\frac 21+\frac 23+\frac 25+\frac 27\right)
\\
+&
\color{magenta}{
\frac 15\left(\frac 21+\frac 23+\frac 25+\frac 27+\frac 29\right)}
\\[3mm]
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
So inductively we would have to extrapolate the role of the magenta terms, then show their equality inductively, explicitly:
$$
\color{magenta}{
\sum_{\substack{1\le j,k\text{ odd}\le 2N\\j+k=2N}}
\frac 1j\cdot\frac 1k
=
\frac 1N\sum_{1\le j\text{ odd}\le 2N}\frac 1j
\ .}
$$
Showing this inductively would break the harmonic beauty, so let us do the job thematically. And this again in the special case $N=5$, since the idea can be easily extrapolated. (It is a typical MZV (multiple zeta values) idea.) The integral form for the equality to be shown is (with $a,b$ playing the roles of $j-1$, $k-1$):
$$
\sum_{\substack{0\le a,b\text{ even}\le 2N-2\\a+b=2N-2}}
\iint_{[0,1]^2}x^a\; y^b\; dx\; dy
=
\frac 2{2N}
\sum_{0\le a\text{ even}\le 2N-2}t^a\; dt
\ .
$$
The idea is now to write the double integral on the square as twice the double integral on the simplex $0\le x\le y\le 1$, then change variables, $y=Y$, $x=tY$ with $t,Y\in[0,1]$. Then (formally) $dx\wedge dy = d(tY)\wedge dY=Y\; dt\wedge dY$, and we get a uniform factor $Y^{a+b+1}=Y^{2N-1}$, and by integration the factor $\frac1{2N}$.

We have now completed also the second part.

---

This became a long answer, but i hope the combinatorial idea behind the steps became in this way easy and transparent.