# How to find Sum of Sum of Partial Harmonic Series: $\sum_{b=1}^{m} \sum_{k=1}^{b} \frac{1}{k} $?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, maple, harmonic-numbers

How do I find the Sum of the Sum of Finitely Many Harmonic Series: $\sum_{b=1}^{m} \sum_{k=1}^{b} \frac{1}{k} $?

According to maple it is:

$\sum_{b=1}^{m} \sum_{k=1}^{b} \frac{1}{k} =  \left(  \left( m+1 \right) ^{2}-m-4 \right)  \left( \Psi \left( m+2
 \right) +\gamma \right) + \left( - \left( m+1 \right) ^{2}+2\,m+5
 \right)  \left( \Psi \left( m+3 \right) +\gamma \right) -3
$

Comment: $\frac{1}{k}$ occurs $m-k+1$ times, so this sum can be written as $\sum_{k=1}^{m}\frac{m-k+1}{k}=(m+1)\sum_{k=1}^{m}\frac{1}{k} - m$ which is $(m+1)H_m-m$ where $H_m$ is the harmonic sum $\sum_{k=1}^{m}\frac{1}{k}.$

Comment: @Thomas Andrews I'm not getting the same numerical result for $(m+1)H_m-m$ and $\sum_{b=1}^{m} \sum_{k=1}^{b} \frac{1}{k}$

Comment: Using the identity $\psi(m + 1) + \gamma = H_m$ and the standard harmonic identity that $H_m = H_{m - 1} + \frac{1}m$, Maple's evaluation can be broken down easily.

Comment: @Bladewood yes thats fine thank you.

Comment: Duplicate of a special case of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2419134/sum-of-powers-of-harmonic-numbers/2919120#2919120

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The iterated sum actually evaluates to
$$\sum_{b = 1}^m \sum_{k = 1}^b \frac{1}k = \left(m + 1\right)H_m - m.$$
You can show by regrouping terms that for a general sum
$$\sum_{a = 1}^x \sum_{b = 1}^a f(b) = \sum_{k = 1}^x \left(x - k + 1\right) f(k).$$
So plugging in $f(b) = \frac{1}b$, we obtain
\begin{align}
\sum_{a = 1}^x \sum_{b = 1}^a f(b) &= \sum_{a = 1}^x \sum_{b = 1}^a \frac{1}b \\
&= \sum_{k = 1}^x \left(x - k + 1\right) \frac{1}k \\
&= \sum_{k = 1}^x \left(\frac{x}k - 1 + \frac{1}k\right) \\
&= \left(x + 1\right)H_x - x.
\end{align}
I'm guessing that Maple just used a weird polygamma identity somewhere.

Comment: I'm not at the moment getting the same numerical result for $\sum_{b=1}^{m} \sum_{k=1}^{b} \frac{1}{k}$ and $=\left(x + 1\right)H_x - x.$ but the maple output does say for m=2 output 5/2 using the weird polygamma stuff in the question.

Comment: $1 + (1 + \frac12) + (1 + \frac12 + \frac13) + (1 + \frac12 + \frac13 + \frac14) = 4 \cdot 1 + 3 \cdot \frac12 + 2 \cdot \frac13 + \frac14 = 5 \cdot (1 + \frac12 + \frac13 + \frac14) - 4$, no?

Comment: yes (2+1)*harmonic(2)-2=5/2 in maple thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Let $S_n$ denotes $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n H_k$ and by applying Abel's summation:

$$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n a_k b_k=A_nb_{n}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}A_k\left(b_k-b_{k+1}\right)\ $$ where $\ \displaystyle A_n=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\ $ and letting $\ \displaystyle a_k=1 $ , $\ \displaystyle b_k=H_k\ $, we get,
\begin{align}
S_n&=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n1\right)H_{n}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(\sum_{i=1}^k1\right)\left(H_k-H_{k+1}\right)\\
&=nH_{n}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(k)\left(-\frac1{k+1}\right), \quad\color{blue}{\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{k}{k+1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{k}{k+1}}\\
&=nH_{n}-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k-1}{k}\\
&=nH_{n}-\sum_{k=1}^n1+\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}\\
&=nH_n-n+H_n
\end{align}

Comment: I like the Abel summation approach - very interesting.

Comment: its very powerful and I use it to solve many tough problems.

Answer (score 1):

Let us use
$$H_k=- \sum_{m=1}^{k}(-1)^k\frac {{k \choose m}}{m},~~ {n \choose r}={n-1 \choose r-1}+{n-1 \choose r},~~ \sum_{k=m}^{n} {k \choose m}= {n+1 \choose m+1}.$$ Then
$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n} H_k=- \sum_{k=1}^{n} \sum_{m=1}^{n} (-1)^m \frac{{n \choose m}}{m}= -\sum_{m=1}^{n} (-1)^{m} \frac{{n+1 \choose m+1}}{m}
$$ $$\Rightarrow S_n= -\sum_{m=1}^{n} (-1)^m \frac{{n \choose m}}{m}- \sum_{m=1}^{n}(-1)^m \frac{{n \choose m+1}}{m}=H_n- \sum_{m=1}^{n} (-1)^m \frac{n}{m(m+1)} {n-1 \choose m+1}$$ $$\Rightarrow S_n=H_n-n\sum_{m=0}^{n} (-1)^m \left( \frac{1}{m}-\frac{1}{m+1} \right) {n-1 \choose m}$$
$$\Rightarrow S_n= H_n-n\sum_{m=1}^{n-1} (-1)^m \frac{{n-1 \choose m}}{m}-\sum_{m=1}^{n}(-1)^m  \frac{n}{m+1} {n-1 \choose m}=H_n+nH_{n-1}-\sum_{m=1}^{n} (-1)^m {n \choose m+1}$$
$$ \Rightarrow S_n= H_n+nH_{n-1}+\sum_{p=2}^{n} (-1)^p {n \choose p}=H_n+n(H_n-\frac{1}{n})+1-n=(n+1)H_n-n.$$

Answer (score 1):

Below I'll show three ways to utilize a generated rule for substitution, to attain the goal. One uses `simplify`, one uses `applyrule`, and one uses `subs`.

Firstly, Maple can convert `harmonic(z)` to sum form, but the reverse operation needs help. I'll construct an equation for use in substitution, from what Maple does actually compute for the `value` of the `Sum` form of `harmonic(z)`.

```
restart;
convert(harmonic(b), Sum):

    Sum(b/_k1/(_k1+b),_k1 = 1 .. infinity)

value(%);

               gamma + Psi(1 + b)
```

So let's construct a formula to utilize,

```
T1 := expand(value(convert(harmonic(z),Sum)) = harmonic(z));

                    1                      
     T1 := Psi(z) + - + gamma = harmonic(z)
                    z
```

Performing only the inner summation,

```
Q1 := Sum(sum(1/k, k=1..b), b=1..m);

       Sum(gamma+Psi(1+b),b = 1 .. m)
```

We can now `simplify` with `T1` as a so-called "side-relation", after substituting `z` for `b` in `Q1`,

```
simplify(subs(b=z,  combine(expand(Q1))), {T1});

       Sum(harmonic(z),z = 1 .. m)
```

At which point Maple does the following,

```
value(%);

      harmonic(m + 1) (m + 1) - m - 1
```

Alternatively we can put `T1` in a slightly different form, isolating for `Psi(z)`,

```
T2 := isolate(T1, Psi(z));

                                          1
     T2 := Psi(z) = harmonic(z) - gamma - -
                                          z
```

Now take the double summation,

```
temp := sum(sum(1/k, k=1..b), b=1..m):

Q2 := simplify(expand(temp),size);

         / 2    \                           2                
         \m  + m/ Psi(m) + 1 + (gamma - 1) m  + (gamma + 1) m
   Q2 := ----------------------------------------------------
                                  m
```

And we can construct a rule from `T2`, for use with the `applyrule` command. This does not entail substituting `m` for `z`.

```
R := subs(Psi(z)=Psi(z::anything), T2):

normal(applyrule(R, Q2));

        harmonic(m) m + harmonic(m) - m
```

There are other ways to use `T2` to substitute for `Psi(z)`. By first substituting `m` for `z` in `T2` we can use `subs` directly.

```
normal(subs(subs(z=m, T2), Q2));

        harmonic(m) m + harmonic(m) - m
```