# The harmonic Series sequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series, harmonic-numbers

Well! I was going through harmonic series from mathworld.worlfram I found harmonic numbers are really tough to calculate I was scribbling and wrote this thing
$$\sum_{k = 1}^{x}H_k= \sum_{k =1}^{x}\left(\sum_{u = 1}^{k}\frac 1{u}\right)$$
How can I simplify these highly complicated things Howe can we find this thing
At the first, we can't find $H_k$ itself and series over series making it a little hard
I wonder how can we simplify this thing?
It's just my curiosity....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well! then I liked this curiosity

I guess by solving you mean just to find only one harmonic number(say: $H_p)$ and finding the above $\sum\sum\frac 1{k}$

This is possible and I solved that by finding a pattern that only the last terms of each harmonic number are making previously calculated harmonic numbers different with only $\frac 1{k-1}$

But for the sake proof of my simplified result, I can provide an easy way

$$\begin{align*}
S 
&=\sum_{k =1}^{x}H_k\\
&=\sum_{k =1}^{x}\sum_{n =1}^{k}\frac 1{n}\\
&=\sum_{k =1}^{x}\frac 1{n}\sum_{k =n}^{x}1\\
& = \sum_{k =1}^{x}\frac 1{n}(x-n+1)\\
& =\sum_{k =1}^{x}\frac {(x+1)-n}{n}\\
& =(x+1)\sum_{k =1}^{x}\frac 1{n} - \sum_{k =1}^{x}1\\
& = (x+1)H_x - x
\end{align*}$$

[image: Python Pr]

Here, **SH()** & **test()** *is our result expected which are equal.*

Comment: Wonderful! Elegant!

Comment: You can simplify code: *sympy.harmonic()*

Comment: @HarryJane  Thanks!
*def test(x):
...     ans1 = sum(list(sympy.harmonic(k) for k in range(1, x+1)))
...     ans2 = (x+1)*sympy.harmonic(x) - x
...     print(bool(ans1==ans2))

Comment: Would like to know how often do you use *sympy* module?

Comment: @HarryJane Hardly, It just for ***prime numbers**, gamma, &zeta function: **sympy.isprime()***

Comment: Nice to meet you! From *France*

Comment: @HarryJane You are texting an introvert!!!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131434/discussion-between-harryjane-and-polymath).